# cleos set contract error Unexpected char '60' in ""

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, wallet

Two weeks ago I tried to use cleos subcommands and everything worked fine. I could set contract to the accounts I created using my own smart contract code. Now whenever I tried set contract or create account, it kept giving this error. I tried changing the config files and rebuilding eos but the program still doesn't seem to work. What can I do here?

[image: cleos bug]

[image: cleos state]

Comment: Hi Tim, I remember running into this error as well a couple of weeks ago, I **think** it was related to the an earlier version of cleos (pre 1.0.2). Which version are you running? I would suggest getting the latest, rebuilding, and make sure you do `sudo make install` from the build directory once the build is complete.

Comment: @Vlad hey Vlad, how would you check the version of cleos? I ran sudo make install and restarted nodeos but still give the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: From the error, it seems that the argument value is not passed. Passed string is "". This seems to be a similar problem - https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3782. Look at nodeos in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're using the wrong flags to generate the ".abi" and ".wast" files.

*Ensure you are using the "-g" flag to generate the ".abi" file and the "-o" flag to generate the ".wast" or ".wasm".*

**The commands you should run are:**

`eosiocpp -o AccountPhoto.wast AccountPhoto.cpp
eosiocpp -g AccountPhoto.abi AccountPhoto.cpp`

Also, you may want to consider switching to the EOSIO.CDT package, which now uses eosio-cpp. The abi and wasm files are also generated in one command (instead of two).